# Flutter access the Notifier on a push page with provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

#### APP DESCRIPTION

My application consists of 3 main pages accessible in my BottomNavigationBar.
When I navigate between the menus I want my pages to be initialized on each call.

In my **Menu1** with my form, I have the possibility to submit my form. This opens a page with a pushNamed that we will call **SubMenu1**. This page displays results calculated based on the form data. On this page I have the possibility to go back with pop and do nothing, or I have a button which must update me certain values ​​of my form.

#### PROBLEM

How to update the values ​​of the **Menu1** form from **SubMenu1**?
Indeed, when you push a page, it ends up at **MaterialApp** level and therefore does not have access to my Notifier from **Menu1**. The solution is to pass the Notifier above **MaterialApp** then.
But suddenly, my form is no longer initialized each time **Menu1** is called, but only once when the application starts ...

#### CODE

In the code provided, I placed the notify above **MaterialApp**.
So I have access to my Notifier in **SubMenu1** and I can modify the values ​​of the fields in **Menu1**, but when I change the page from my navigation bar and return the values ​​are still present, the page has not initialized .

**AppScreen** :

```
class AppScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<LicenseNotifier>(
      create: (_) => LicenseNotifier(),
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider<BottomNavigationBarNotifier>( // Here my navigation 
        create: (BuildContext context) => BottomNavigationBarNotifier(),
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider<Menu1Notifier>( // Here my form Notifier for Menu 1
          create: (BuildContext context) => Menu1Notifier(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: AppConfig.APPLICATION_NAME,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: AppTheme().data,
            initialRoute: AppRoutes.HOME,
            onGenerateRoute: RoutesClass.generate,
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

My BottomNavigationBarNotifier :

```
class BottomNavigationBarNotifier with ChangeNotifier {

  int currentIndex = AppConfig.NAVIGATION_DEFAULT_INDEX;

  BottomNavigationBarNotifier();

  Future<void> navigationScreenIndex({int index}) async{
    currentIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Widget loadScreenWithNavigation()
  {
    switch (currentIndex)
    {
      case 0:
        return Menu1Screen(title: 'Menu 1');
        break;

      case 1:
        return Menu2Screen(title: 'Menu 2');
        break;

      case 2:
        return Menu3Screen(title: 'Menu 3');
        break;

      default:
        return Menu1Screen(title: 'Menu 1');
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

My notifier for **Menu1Screen** :

```
class Menu1Notifier extends FormNotifier {

  TextEditingController controllerTest;
  
  Menu1Notifier (){
    _initialise();
  }

  Future _initialise() async{
    controllerTest = TextEditingController();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you are doing from the code fragments above, but I think I understand the requirement:

- Menu1 has state
- SubMenu1 should be able to read and update the Menu1 state
- Menu1 invokes SubMenu1 as a "child" screen, there is no other path to SubMenu1

The simplest way to handle such simple state is for Menu1 to pass its state to SubMenu1 (as a constructor argument) when it displays it, and for SubMenu1 to update it directly. I have shown example code for this below. Of course, this is tight coupling between the two screens, but then it seems to be a tightly coupled requirement.

The Provider package is useful to separate the state from the UI. You can use this approach. You say *"But suddenly, my form is no longer initialized each time Menu1 is called, but only once when the application starts"*. Surely Menu1 can make a call to a method to initialise the Provider when it is invoked? I have added example code for the Provider approach. Some brief notes:

- I use MultiProvider, even though I only have one ChangeNotifierProvider, this would make your code easier to read
- The ChangeNotifier FormData holds the form state
- The parent form initialises the form state
- Both forms call FormData methods to set and get the state

Long example code direct state follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FormTest(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormTest extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _FormTestState createState() => _FormTestState();
}

class _FormTestState extends State<FormTest> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _options = [
    FormWidget(),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.deepOrange),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.green)
  ];
  void _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Example'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal),
      body: Center(
        child: _options.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
                backgroundColor: Colors.teal),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: 'Profile',
                backgroundColor: Colors.cyan),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: 'Settings',
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            ),
          ],
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          iconSize: 40,
          onTap: _onItemTap,
          elevation: 5),
    );
  }
}

class PlaceholderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;

  PlaceholderWidget(this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
    );
  }
}

class FormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FormWidgetState createState() {
    return FormWidgetState();
  }
}

class FormWidgetState extends State<FormWidget> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _formData = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
            onSaved: (value) {
              _formData['parent'] = value;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState!.save();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Parent text: ' + _formData['parent'])));
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => SubFormWidget(_formData)),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: Text('SubForm'),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState!.save();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Subform text: ' + _formData['child'])));
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubFormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map _formData;
  SubFormWidget(this._formData);

  @override
  SubFormWidgetState createState() {
    return SubFormWidgetState();
  }
}

class SubFormWidgetState extends State<SubFormWidget> {
  final _subFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _subFormKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Example'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(widget._formData['parent']),
            TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (value) {
                widget._formData['child'] = value;
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_subFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    _subFormKey.currentState!.save();
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text(
                            'Subform text: ' + widget._formData['child'])));
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Long example code for Provider approach:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<FormData>(
          create: (ctx) => FormData(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: FormTest2(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  FormTest2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormTest2State createState() => _FormTest2State();
}

class _FormTest2State extends State<FormTest2> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _options = [
    FormWidget2(),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.deepOrange),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.green)
  ];
  void _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Example 2'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal),
      body: Center(
        child: _options.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
                backgroundColor: Colors.teal),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: 'Profile',
                backgroundColor: Colors.cyan),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: 'Settings',
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            ),
          ],
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          iconSize: 40,
          onTap: _onItemTap,
          elevation: 5),
    );
  }
}

class PlaceholderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;

  PlaceholderWidget(this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
    );
  }
}

class FormWidget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FormWidget2State createState() {
    return FormWidget2State();
  }
}

class FormData extends ChangeNotifier {
  var _formData = <String, String>{};

  void init() {
    _formData = <String, String>{};
    // No notifyListeners() needed in this use case
  }

  void setEntry(String key, String value) {
    _formData[key] = value;
    // notifyListeners() may or may not be needed in this use case
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String getEntry(String key) {
    var value = _formData[key];
    return value;
  }
}

class FormWidget2State extends State<FormWidget2> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<FormData>(context, listen: false).init();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<FormData>(
      builder: (context, formData, _) => Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              initialValue: formData.getEntry('parent'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (value) {
                formData.setEntry('parent', value);
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    _formKey.currentState.save();
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text(
                            'Parent text: ' + formData.getEntry('parent'))));
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SubFormWidget2()),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: Text('SubForm'),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    _formKey.currentState.save();
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text(
                            'Subform text: ' + formData.getEntry('child'))));
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubFormWidget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SubFormWidget2State createState() {
    return SubFormWidget2State();
  }
}

class SubFormWidget2State extends State<SubFormWidget2> {
  final _subFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _subFormKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Example 2'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal),
        body: Consumer<FormData>(
          builder: (context, formData, _) => Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(formData.getEntry('parent')),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: formData.getEntry('child'),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  formData.setEntry('child', value);
                },
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_subFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      _subFormKey.currentState.save();
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text(
                              'Subform text: ' + formData.getEntry('child'))));
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Submit'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```